# PHP get all cookies set in web application

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Is there any way to get all cookies set in php application (with no request) ? I want to do something like this:

```
setcookie("cookieName", "test");
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Above code of course doesn't work (work only when app is requested by browser)

Comment: Cookies are stored in browser.

Comment: It's `$_COOKIE` without an S, for starters. That's an array of cookies sent by the browser - cookies you set won't show up in it.

Comment: @frz3993 Yes, but before are stored in browser, you need to create them

Comment: I don't want display cookies that sent by browser but earlier step: get cookie after set cookie header

Comment: Yes, and I want to get cookies from header that is not send yet

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.headers-list.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `headers_list()` which will give you an array of headers that are ready to be sent to the client,

`headers_list(); //doesn't take any params`

eg result:

`Array ( [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 [1] => Set-Cookie: cookieName=test )`

Answer (score 0):

Most of your question can be answered by just visiting the [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) php manual.

Cookies cannot be verified until the next page load.  You can manually set `$_COOKIE['test']` at the time you call setcookie although this value will not be persistent if the user's browser does not store the cookie.

Other than storing the values yourself, you can use [headers_list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to return what headers will be, or have been, sent by PHP, but as stated earlier, this will not verify the cookie has actually been set on the user side.